# Binding a DataTrigger value to this instance of DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding, datatrigger

I have a `ListView`, with its items represented by an `ItemTemplate` like so:

```
<ListView dependencyObjects:InterestingItem.Interesting="{Binding InterestingItem}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Quotations}" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="NotImportant">
                    </StackPanel>

                    <Grid x:Name="HiddenGrid"
                          Background="Red"
                          Visibility="Hidden" >
                        <Grid.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Grid.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.InterestingItem, 
                                                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView }}}" 
                                                               Value="*this instance here*!">
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Grid.Triggers>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Style>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The `ListView` has an attached property `InterestingItem` that is one of the items in the `ListView`.

What I can't hook up is when the `InterestingItem` is the same as one of the items, the second `Grid` should become visible.

I would prefer not to change and bind to the actual objects in the list - but rather have the `ListView` control which item is to be altered.

What is the `Value` in the `DataTrigger` that I need?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your XAML and conceptually that prevent it from working.

- To bind attached properties, you have to use the correct syntax with parentheses.

  ```
  Path="{Binding (local:InterestingItem.Interesting), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
  ```

  See the [Binding path syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netdesktop-5.0#binding-path-syntax) documenation for reference.
- The `Triggers` property does only support `EventTriggers`, see [`FrameworkElement.Triggers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.triggers?view=windowsdesktop-5.0).

  > Note that the collection of triggers established on an element only supports EventTrigger, not property triggers (Trigger). If you require property triggers, you must place these within a style or template and then assign that style or template to the element either directly through the Style property, or indirectly through an implicit style reference.
- You cannot bind the [`Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger.value?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) property of `DataTrigger`, since it is not a dependency property.

You could of course change the bound type to expose a property that indicates if it is a special object or not and bind that in XAML using a `DataTrigger`, similar to this (where `IsSpecial` is the new `bool` property).

```
<Grid x:Name="HiddenGrid"
      Background="Red">
   <TextBlock Text="Hidden Grid"/>
   <Grid.Style>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type Grid}">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSpecial}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

If you want to stick to your current approach, you could create a custom [`IMultiValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) that enables binding multiple properties. It would check if all of the bound values are equal and return `Visibility.Visible` or `Visibility.Hidden` otherwise. This example uses Linq to check this and supports an arbitrary number of values bound, but there are many other options.

```
public class EqualityToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (values is null || values.Length < 2)
         return Binding.DoNothing;

      return values.Distinct().Count() == 1 ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
   }

   public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

Next, instantiate the converter in the resources of the `ListView` or any other resource dictionary in scope and bind the `Visibility` property of the `Grid` to both the current item (just `<Binding/>`) and the attached property `local:InterestingItem.Interesting` with a [`MultiBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.multibinding?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) that uses the converter to convert them to a `Visibility`.

```
<ListView local:InterestingItem.Interesting="{Binding InterestingItem}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Quotations}">
   <ListView.Resources>
      <local:EqualityToVisibilityConverter x:Key="EqualityToVisibilityConverter"/>
   </ListView.Resources>
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Border>
            <Grid>
               <StackPanel x:Name="NotImportant">
                  <TextBlock Text="Not Important"/>
               </StackPanel>
               <Grid x:Name="HiddenGrid"
                     Background="Red">
                  <Grid.Visibility>
                     <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityToVisibilityConverter}">
                        <Binding/>
                        <Binding Path="(local:InterestingItem.Interesting)"
                                 RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}"/>
                     </MultiBinding>
                  </Grid.Visibility>
                  <TextBlock Text="Hidden Grid"/>
               </Grid>
            </Grid>
         </Border>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

There are two other things to note here. I have added two dummy `TextBlock`s, otherwise the result will not be visible, as the panels are empty. Replace them with your content. Furthermore, both the `StackPanel` and the `Grid` are overlapping in the parent `Grid`, I do not know if this is intentional or not, but you can change it by adding rows or columns and moving the elements there.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the Value in the DataTrigger that I need?

I am afraid XAML has no support for something like the `this` keyword in C#.

You may use a `MultiBinding` with an `IMultiValueConverter` implementation that determines whether the items are equal:

```
<Grid x:Name="HiddenGrid" Background="Red">
    <Grid.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Grid">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <MultiBinding>
                            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                <local:MultiConverter />
                            </MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <Binding Path="{Binding Path=DataContext.InterestingItem, 
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView }}}" />
                            <Binding Path="{Binding}" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Style>
</Grid>
```

**Converter:**

```
public class MultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        values != null && values.Length == 2 && values[0] == values[1];

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Note that you cannot set the `Visibility` property of the `Grid` to a local value if you want to be able to override the value using a `Style` setter.

```
 <Grid x:Name="HiddenGrid" Background="Red" Visibility="Hidden">
```